# Default Split Screen on Ubuntu

Tags: shortcut-keys

I'm new to Ubuntu and currently trying to make my workflow more efficient. Is there a functionality to open windows in the side-by-side split screen by default? A quick google search didn't help and only brought up shortcuts to position the windows manually by super + left/right after start up.

Comment: AFAIK only these: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/shell-windows.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Quick answer*: essentially No.

*Long answer*: There is almost no build-in possibility to control the window position and characteristics of newly opened application windows. The only control available is whether you want new windows positioned in the center, or according to a "smart" algorithm. That setting even is not exposed by default. It is however available in "Gnome Tweaks" (not installed by default) on the "Windows" tab.

It is essentially the application itself that controls the size and position of a new opened window. The behavior depends on the application. Many applications nowadays will reopen the window in the state it was when last closed. Other applications will remember size and position per document, some may just start with a fixed default size and position, etc.

The behavior you are looking for is implemented in an other kind of window manager, the so called [tiling window managers](https://freedompenguin.com/articles/desktop/exploring-tiling-window-managers/), such as i3 or bspwm. Tiling window managers, however, currently are more targeted to advanced users or developpers, and require quite some setup. Some distributions are appearing that reconfigure a desktop that uses a tiling window manager (e.g. [Regolith linux](https://regolith-linux.org/), which you can also install in a regular Ubuntu install, or [Manjaro i3 edition](https://manjaro.org/get-manjaro/)). The philosophy and approach of tiling window managers is quite different, and they require a learning curve.